# Referring to a class's height in less

Tags: less

I just got into LESS this morning. It's a lot nicer to write than pure css, BUT it would really solve a big headache for me if it was possible to refer to attribute from classes within classes...

Say I have

```
#El1
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

I'd like to do something like

```
#El2
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: #El1.height;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

So `#El1` can size itself whichever way it wants and `#El2` can be positioned beneath it and fill the entire remained for the viewport.

Not matter how hard I google I can't find anything to seem to indicate that this is possible. From how I understand the processing of the stylesheet takes place on load, my hunch is that this can't be done, because the height of `El1` isn't known by the time the css rules are processed. But just on the off chance that there is a way to do this, I thought I'd ask... so is there any way that this can be done?

Comment: less compiles to a stylesheet so much as I know. I don't think less itself has anything to do with browsers per say

Comment: You are correct, "the height of `El1` isn't known" because LESS is a CSS _preprocessor_ (it processes before compiling to CSS and before loading into a browser). To read height as you desire would have to be done with javascript.

Comment: @ScottS I see, thanks for confirming.